# Configure completely independent users on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm currently creating my own cloud gaming machine and was wondering if it's possible to have 2 users use the computer at the same time with each having their own apps, own desktop, etc. And of course I would need them to be able to use the same apps at the same time.

What I've tried already is simply connect through RDP on my main account then create a second user and connect to it with RDP. But if I launch Steam on one user then try to simultaneously open Steam on the other user the first Steam process will be closed.

When doing research I came across RDS and MultiPoint but I'm not sure what I should use or even how to set it up for my purpose.

The version of Windows Server I'm using is the 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not working. Wrong tree you are barking.

Let's start with legal and implications.

- Unless you use Terminal Server (AND LICENSING) you are limited to 2 users that both are ADMINS. Generally that is not what you want on a cloud gaming machine. The admin part means they are neither separate nor can you control what they do.
- Unless you connect to the physical session (admin session) you do not really use the GPU. You run on some very virtualized stuff. This is not want RDP is made for - and gaming without GPU... nope.
- Steam: I am quite sure noone there did think about multiple users at the same time. Keeping those totally separate may be harder than you think. NOT SURE though - needs SERIOUS testing.

Basically: This is not how it is supposed to work. The one way it WAS supposed to work on INTRANET - only - was using Hyper-V and then using a physical GPU mapping to windows desktop VM's. This is retired technology, though (named RemoteFX) and was meant for Intranet, so say welcome to 100+ megabit bandwidth.

RDP is not and never was meant to run real games on it and you may not like the results of that (as in: it is basically not usable generally, with SOME exceptions possible).